# Moving an object forward relative to the distance traveled by another object

Tags: unity

I am trying to achieve the camera follow like Ketchapp's game "Zigzag".

I will try to explain the best I can; I have two objects, Player (a sphere) and Camera:

- Player can only move to the left and forward.
- Camera moves forward and always keeps the same distance from the player.

I have tried different things like moving the camera and player at the same speed and decreasing/increasing the speed of camera depending on the distance between them, but in vain.

You can watch the gameplay here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XbPcubaTJI
Note how the camera follows the player and just moves forward (not to the left or to the right).

Comment: um I might need you to point out where's the difficult bit in that video, because all I saw is a view that continuously scrolls up at constant speed.

Comment: Almost certainly neither the player nor the camera are moving, but rather that the level itself is scrolling past.

Comment: At first I thought the same but I find it hard to implement in 3D, can you explain how you will go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The player is just moving left to right. The player is not moving forward and the camera isn't moving forward either. The scrolling background gives the impression of moving forward.

So to achieve a camera to follow like "Zigzag", well you just don't move your camera at all, but move the level!

Comment: It is very easy in 2D to move the level instead of camera but I have no idea how to even start thinking this method in 3D specifically regarding this situation.

Comment: How can I synchronize the player's movement speed with the level's movement speed.

Comment: @DaniyalAzram The player *only moves left and right* there is no forward/backward motion of the player at all